# How to use Pillow to set RGB value of a PNG based on a binary mask

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, png

I have an PNG image and a black-and-white mask. This post (https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-putalpha/) demonstrated how to use `putalpha()` to send the alpha channel of the image so the masked out area becomes transparent. I wonder if there is any function in Pillow can actually change the RGB value of the masked out area into all 255?

Following is an example. The result image should have all white area actually have RGB value of 255, instead of only have alpha being set as 0.

[image: The original image] [image: The mask] [image: The image I want to get, the white area should have RGB value of 255.]

**Updated question**

(I run into some error when I try to use `ImageChops`:

Here is the code I ran:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

im = Image.open('lena.jpg')
mask = Image.open('mask_circle.png')

print(im, mask)
darker = ImageChops.darker(im, mask)
darker.save('darker.png')
```

And the error I got:

```
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=400x225 at 0x24725330BF0> <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=400x225 at 0x24724F2CD40>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    darker = ImageChops.darker(im, mask)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\...\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageChops.py", line 81, in darker
    return image1._new(image1.im.chop_darker(image2.im))
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: images do not match
```

Comment: if you're worried about the *transparent area* still retaining its RGB values, you can just change those as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Maybe @ChristophRackwitz has deduced in the comments what you want  - to actually zero out the transparent pixels so they cannot be recovered if someone later removes the alpha/transparency channel. If so, you can use:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

# Load image and mask
im = Image.open('lena.jpg')
mask = Image.open('mask.png')

# Zero out all areas that will become transparent
darker = ImageChops.darker(im,mask)
```

[image]

```
# Push alpha channel to make surrounding area transparent
darker.putalpha(mask.convert('L'))
darker.save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

**Original Answer**

Your question doesn't make much sense to me. If you set the RGB values to 255 within the mask, the image will become white and you'll end up with your mask - which you already have.

Maybe you mean you want to retain the rest of the Lena picture but just set the face to white and leave the remainder of the image *"as is"*. if that is the case you can use a ***Lighten*** blending mode which will simply select the brighter pixel at every location in both images - so it will select white where the mask is white and Lena everywhere else because that will certainly be brighter than the black of the mask:

```
PIL import Image, ImageChops

# Load image and mask
im = Image.open('lena.jpg')
mask = Image.open('mask.png')

# Select whichever is lighter at each pixel location
res = ImageChops.lighter(im,mask)
res.save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! But your code throw an error when I run it:

ValueError: images do not match

Comment: Try checking the size, shape and so on, of your images after loading, e.g. `print(im,mask)`

Comment: I did check the size, they are identical: <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=400x225 at 0x20FE296D430> <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=400x225 at 0x20FE2A19910>

Comment: Mmmm... try editing your question, and pasting in the exact code you ran and the full error message - carefully identifying which line caused the error.

Comment: I don't know what's going wrong. Try making an RGB version of the mask and passing that to `ImageChops.darker()` like this `darker = ImageChops.darker(im, mask.convert('RGB'))`

Comment: Ha, it works after the conversion, thanks a million!